# How do you calculate numpy arrays in certain cases?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new to programming and am starting to learn Python.. I want to ask something, for example I have code like this

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
import numpy as np


data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3, 3], [1, 1, 2, 1]]))

weights = np.array([0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6])

n = data.max().max()
dummies = pd.get_dummies(data.T.astype(CategoricalDtype(categories=np.arange(1, n + 1))))
result = weights.dot(dummies).reshape(data.shape[0], n)
result = np.argmax(result, axis=1) + 1
result = np.sum(result)

print(result)
```

the results of the above program is `7`

what I'm asking is how, if the `weight` variable has a few rows like this.

```
weights = np.array([[0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6],
                    [0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4],
                    [0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3]])
```

which part of the syntax should I change?

The results I want are like this
`[7 .. .. .. .. ..]`<< this result depends on the number of rows in the `weight` variable

Answer (score 0):

You have no comments in your code. So I introudced variables `weights1`, `weights2`, `result1`, and `result2` to trace results and compare the logic.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
import numpy as np


data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3, 3], [1, 1, 2, 1]]))

weights1 = np.array([0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6])
weights2 = np.array([[0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6],
                    [0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4],
                    [0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3]])

n = data.max().max()
dummies = pd.get_dummies(data.T.astype(CategoricalDtype(categories=np.arange(1, n + 1))))

result1 = weights1.dot(dummies).reshape(data.shape[0], n)
result2 = weights2.dot(dummies).reshape(data.shape[0], n, weights2.shape[0])

result1 = np.argmax(result1, axis=1) + 1
result2 = np.argmax(result2, axis=2) + 1

result1 = np.sum(result1)
result2 = np.sum(result2,1)

print(result1)
print(result2)
```

Output:

```
7
[7 5 4]
```